# $0$ inner product implies constant function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $I=(0,1)$ and $u\in L^\infty(I)$ is a piece-wise positive constant function with finitely many pieces over $I$.

Suppose
$$
\int_I uv\,dx=0
$$
for all $v\in L^1(I)$ such that 
$$
\int v\, dx=0.
$$

Then, would it possible to prove that $u\equiv c$ for some constant $c>0$ over the entire domain $I$?

Thank you!

Comment: Sure: take $v = u - \int u\, dx$, and note that $ \int v^2\, dx = \int uv\, dx = 0$.

Comment: @ErickWong got it. Thx!

Comment: @ErickWong How could that prove $ u \equiv c$ ?

Comment: @vidyarthi It proves $v\equiv 0$, so $u \equiv \int u\, dx$, which is a constant.